# Top 5 records from a sub query, i'm getting "Incorrect syntax near"-error

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to find the top 5 values from a sub query using the following code but is is not working.

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

the inner query works fine it retrives the percentages but the out query gives me the error.

```
select Top 5 cde 
from 
(
   select MCC, sum(Refunds_per_CIF) as cde
   from 
   (
     select MCC, 10000*Refunds/Sum(PV)  over()  as Refunds_per_CIF
     from san
    ) as t
   group by MCC
)
order by cde
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi Schmelter it retrieves this mesage Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. the inner query works fine it retrives the percentages but the out query gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL sub-queries require a table-alias, so try this:

```
select Top 5 ChooseAMeaningfulName.cde 
from 
(
   select MCC, sum(Refunds_per_CIF) as cde
   from 
   (
     select MCC, 10000*Refunds/Sum(PV)  over()  as Refunds_per_CIF
     from san
    ) as t
   group by MCC
) AS ChooseAMeaningfulName
order by cde
```

Comment: Hi Tim sorry to bother you again I am just wonder whether there is a way to extract the top n directly from the subquery   select MCC, 10000*Refunds/Sum(PV)  over()  as Refunds_per_CIF
     from san

Comment: instead of two subquery(current now) you can eliminate one by using ranking function. use the ranking function in the select MCC statement and then use where to filter the rank alias